# Cypress custom command with no prev subject not working?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm having problems getting to grips with prevSubject in custom commands. Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong here? I've created the following simple example:
Commands.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("want2", {prevSubject: 'element'}, (subject) => {
    expect(subject).to.exist
})
Cypress.Commands.add("want3", {prevSubject: false}, (subject) => {
    expect(subject).to.exist
})
```

In my spec:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="Flinstone"]').want2()
// the above works
cy.want3(cy.get('[data-tc="Flinstone"]')
// the above results in a Cypress command timeout after 4s. Why?
```

When I run the test, the call to want2 works fine, but then the call to want3 results in a timeout after 4s - even though the element is clearly there! What am I getting wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: It works on my machine, could you provide the full code or something like a codesanbox?

Comment: hi @konekoya ... Thanks for your help - it got me thinking! So I tried a fresh install of cypress, and set up the simplest of tests as above.... And just like you it worked fine! So then bit by bit I've tried copying things over from my main cypress install where I see the problem - and unless I'm mistaken I've now copied everything over to the fresh install folder - and it works!

I'm going to look closer, try to work out where the two installations differ, but Im currently pleased it's working, and confused as to why it is / isn't in the different install folders! 

Thanks again!

Comment: So further investigation - The difference between my two installs was Cypress 4.7 vs 4.11! Upgrade the broken one to (actually 4.12 by then!)... It works fine!